# Flask Build Error

Tags: python, html, sqlite, flask

When I fill in the form I get this error, I dont see the flash message although its added it to my db:

```
werkzeug.routing.BuildError
BuildError: ('/contacts', {}, None)
```

my methods:

```
@app.route('/contacts/', methods=['GET','POST'])
def contact_list():
    cur = g.db.execute('select contact_id, surname, firstname from address order by surname')
    contacts = cur.fetchall()
    return render_template("contacts.html", contacts = contacts) #refer to template


@app.route('/addcontact/', methods=['GET','POST'])
def contact_add():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        g.db.execute('insert into address (surname, firstname, email, mobile) values (?, ?, ?, ?)',
                 [request.form['firstname'], request.form['surname'], request.form['email']
                , request.form['mobile']])
        g.db.commit()
        flash('New entry was successfully posted')
        return redirect(url_for('/contacts')) #redirect to the contacts page
    elif request.method != 'POST':
        return render_template('addcontact.html')
```

My html:

```
<html>
  <body>
      <h1>Add new contact</h1>
  <form action='/addcontact/' method="post">
    <dl>
      <dt>First Name:
      <dd><input type="text" size=30 name="firstname">
      <dt>Surname:
      <dd><input type="text" size=30 name="surname">
      <dt>Email:
      <dd><input type="text" size=30 name="email">
      <dt>Mobile:
      <dd><input type="text" size=30 name="mobile">            
      <dd><input type="submit" value="Add New Contact">
    </dl>
  </form>
  <a href="/">Home</a>
  <a href="/contact">List of contacts</a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `url_for()` call fails; you need to give it the route *name*, not the url. The exception is raised because there is no `/contacts` route. This should work:

```
url_for('contact_list')
```

Because you called `g.db.commit()` the new contact has already been committed to the database by the time the `url_for()` call raises an exception.